# Получение данных ajax'ом из php-обработчика

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Добрый день!
Имеется форма поиска:

```
  <form method="POST" action="simple_search.php" id="form_id" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="usersearch" size="50" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Искать" id="submit" />
  </form>
```

И div для вывода результатов:

```
<div id="result></div>
```

Ajax'ом отправляется запрос php-Обработчику:

```
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
    var $form = $("#form_id");
    $.ajax({
      cashe: false,
      type: $form.attr('method'),
      url: $form.attr('action'),
      data: $form.serialize(),
    }).done(function() {
      console.log('success');
    }).fail(function() {
      console.log('fail');
    });
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Обработчик ищет по базе и выводит результаты:

```
$user_search = $_POST['usersearch'];
  if(!empty($user_search)) {
  $query_usersearch = "SELECT * FROM docs
                       WHERE title LIKE '%$user_search%'
                       OR description LIKE '%$user_search%'
                       OR keywords LIKE '%$user_search%'";
  $result_usersearch = mysqli_query($link, $query_usersearch);
  while($array_usersearch = mysqli_fetch_array($result_usersearch)) {
      echo $array_usersearch['title'];
      echo $array_usersearch['description'];
  }
}
```

Вопрос: как эти результаты с помощью всё того же ajax-запроса поместить в div #result? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На [данной странице](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81) есть прекрасный пример:

```
$.ajax({
 url: "some.php",
 success: function(data){
  alert( "Прибыли данные: " + data );
 }
});
```

Это означает, что Вам лучше использовать callback функцию success (с ajax вообще лучше использовать всегда callback), а Ваш код преобразится примерно вот так:

```
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
var $form = $("#form_id");
$.ajax({
  cashe: false,
  type: $form.attr('method'),
  url: $form.attr('action'),
  data: $form.serialize(),
  success: function(data) {
      $("#result").html(data);
      console.log('success');
  },
  error: function() {
      console.log("error");
  }
});
e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: Всё ок! Спасибо!

Comment: @humster_spb странные вы люди сообщества :) ответ ниже дан раньше и абсолютно такой же, и вы(автор ответа) его позже отредактировали. Добавив такое же решение что и в предыдущем ответе.

Comment: я ответ не редактировал - я оставил коммент, но потом удалил его за бессмысленностью ) и я не автор ответа - я вопрошающий :))

Comment: @Naumov я считаю, что нужно давать не просто готовый код, а объяснить почему так сделал, что я сначала и сделал, потом только дошло, что лучше еще и готовый код прикрепить.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $("#form_id");
    $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      type: $form.attr('method'),
      url: $form.attr('action'),
      data: $form.serialize(),
      success: function(result) {
          $('#result').html(result);
      }
    }).done(function() {
      console.log('success');
    }).fail(function() {
      console.log('fail');
    });
});
```

Comment: preventDefaut вроде устарел?

Comment: вроде как тут -> https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/ не написано, что это deprecated

Comment: @KonstantinMitjurin Я всё равно за проголосовал. Просто firefox постоянно на preventDefault выводит notice у меня

Comment: @Naumov, странно что об этом устаревании не пишут в MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault